# Mongo DB goes slow with increase in number of records

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

We Used mongo and its working fine on testing server(i think due to less number of records) but when we move to production it goes slow. even simple queries taking around 10s time.

I had checked indexes too there are proper indexes already defined.

Query

```
       db.products.aggregate([{
       "$match": {
           "tenant_id": 1031
       }
   }, {
       "$sort": {
           "id": -1
       }
   }, {
       "$skip": 0
   }, {
       "$limit": 20
   }]
)
```

Explain Result

```
// collection: products
{
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong("0"),
    "stages" : [
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "tenant_id" : 1031
                },
                "sort" : {
                    "id" : NumberInt("-1")
                },
                "limit" : NumberLong("20"),
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : NumberInt("1"),
                    "namespace" : "dbname.products",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "tenant_id" : {
                            "$eq" : 1031
                        }
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "tenant_id" : {
                                "$eq" : 1031
                            }
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "id" : NumberInt("-1")
                            },
                            "indexName" : "id",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : NumberInt("1"),
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "id" : [
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Please let me know what i can do make it fast

Comment: Your obfuscation made the code confusing. Why for query on field `yyyy`, index `xxxx` was chosen? Review all other renames too.

Comment: hey @SergioTulentsev please check now

Comment: It's no less confusing now. Why is key `xxx`, but selected index is on `id`? And those index bounds, are they really what you are getting?

Comment: Hey @SergioTulentsev i Think it will be clear now 

i think its taking id index due to sorting and yes i am getting the same index bounds

Comment: Do you have index on `tenant_id`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes we have 

{
    "tenant_id" : 1
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly support this query, you need a compound index on `{tenant_id: 1, id: -1}`. The first part helps filtering, the second one - enables fast sorting of the filtered results.

Some documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#sort-order